# ASP.NET core 2.2: what is the safest way of sharing request-specific data between framework classes?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out which is the cleanest and safest way to share some request-specific data between framework classes in an ASP.NET core 2.2 web application.

When I say *framework classes* I mean classes like middlewares or authorization handlers, broadly speaking the framework classes involved in the process of handling the user request.

The idea of sharing I'm looking for is having some sort of implicit request context or request data bag that is accessible from all the framework classes involved in the HTTP request handling.

In the past I did something similar in .NET core console applications by using the [AsyncLocal class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netcore-2.2).

The possible alternatives I have found are the followings:

- using a custom service as a bag of data and register it as a `scoped` service on the ASP.NET core DI container
- using the [HttpContext.Items property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.items?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as a way to save data for a specific request context

Which is the best approach to accomplish what I'm trying to do ? Are there other ways to do so in ASP.NET core ?

As a sidenote, is it safe to use the [AsyncLocal class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netcore-2.2) as a way to share data between classes inside an entire ASP.NET core request handling flow ? I didn't find any microsoft guidelines about the usage of AsyncLocal with ASP.NET core

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You practically answered yourself (which is a huge plus, because you not only asked a proper question but did research on possible solutions).

Using items of HttpContext is the simplest and the most straightforward way. But it comes with the pain of casting the object when receiving values, maybe serializing and remembering the key under which you would store it (otherwise you are gonna end up with [magic strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string)).

On the other hand, using scoped service is more mature and dedicated way. If you know what to expect in your data bag, then you could implement a complex service for it with properties and maybe more narrowed down sections. That way, receiving data would be sheer pleasure.

I suggest you to analyse the real demand and how frequently that logic would be used. Whether it's going to be used in many places or is it just once, maybe two times scenario. Having that in mind you should be perfectly capable of making the right decision.

Sadly, I know nothing about using `AsyncLocal<T>` in ASP.NET Core.